# How to scale down blocks without causing pixel overlapping

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, scale, pixel

I have a bunch of blocks that needs to be drawn into a grid. Now displaying them unscaled everything is fine but when I try to scale them down to fit withing a window I get "scale-artifacts" because I use a normal scale-ratio formula and floats.

Is there a way to avoid these problems ?

Common example data:

```
Original length: 200000
```

Scaled down to a `25x25 pixel grid` (it's this small for development and debugging)
The scaled down max length: 625 (25 * 25)

```
Scale-ratio: (625 / 200000) = 0,003125
```

**Example data 1 - overlapping, scaled blocks overwrite each other**
Start of block => end of block: [start, end)

```
1: 2100 => 2800
2: 2800 => 3600
3: 3600 => 4500
4: 4500 => 5500
```

Jumping over showing the output of this example because I think example 2 and 3 will get the point across. Left it in for completeness.

**Example data 2 - incorrect space between 2 and 3**
Start of block => end of block: [start, end)

```
1: 960 => 1440
2: 1440 => 1920
3: 1920 => 2400

1: 960 => 1440, length: 480, scaled length: 1.5:
2: 1440 => 1920, length: 480, scaled length: 1.5:
3: 1920 => 2400, length: 480, scaled length: 1.5:
```

pixel start, end, length

```
1: 3, 0, 1
2: 4, 0, 1
3: 6, 0, 1
```

Displayed grid:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
...
```

**Example data 3 - 1 moved a step back incorrectly**
Start of block => end of block: [start, end)

```
1: 896 => 1344
2: 1344 => 1792
3: 1792 => 2240

1: 896 => 1344, length: 448, scaled length: 1.4:
2: 1344 => 1792, length: 448, scaled length: 1.4:
3: 1792 => 2240, length: 448, scaled length: 1.4:
```

pixel start, end, length

```
1: 2, 0, 1
2: 4, 0, 1
3: 5, 0, 1
```

Displayed grid:

```
[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
...
```

What example data 2 and 3 should have looked like:

```
[ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
...
```

Remember the block values are [start, end)

**Preemptive strike (down-voters / trollers) Remember: I'm not psychic or a mind-reader. If you want to give negative do it in a constrictive way or it is useless (i will not learn anything) and will just pollute the thread.**

**Update**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <utility> // pair
#include <algorithm> // for_each

using namespace std;

const size_t width_size = 25; // 25 pixels
const size_t height_size = 25; // 25 pixels
const size_t grid_length = width_size * height_size; // width * height
array<size_t, grid_length> grid;

const size_t original_length = 200000;

typedef pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> block;
vector<block> test_values;

void show_grid()
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height_size; ++y) {
        const size_t start_pos_for_current_heigth = y * width_size;
        const size_t end_pos_for_current_heigth = start_pos_for_current_heigth + width_size;

        cout << "[ ";
        for (size_t i = start_pos_for_current_heigth; i < end_pos_for_current_heigth; ++i) {
            if (i + 1 < end_pos_for_current_heigth)
                cout << grid[i] << ", ";
            else
                cout << grid[i];
        };
        cout << " ]" << endl;
    }
}

void scale_and_add(const float scale)
{
    size_t test_value_id = 1;

    for_each(test_values.cbegin(), test_values.cend(), [&](const block &p) {
        const float s_f = p.first * scale;
        const unsigned long s = round(s_f);
        const float e_f = p.second * scale;
        const unsigned long e = round(e_f);
        const unsigned long block_length = p.second - p.first;
        const float block_length_scaled = block_length * scale;
        assert(s <= grid_length);
        assert(e <= grid_length);

        cout << test_value_id << ":" << endl;
        cout << " " << p.first << " => " << p.second << " length: " << block_length << endl;
        cout << " " << s << " (" << s_f << ") => " << e << " (" << e_f << ") length: " << (e - s) << " (" << block_length_scaled << ")" << " (scaled)" << endl;

        for (size_t i = s; i < e; ++i) {
            if (grid[i] != 0) {
                cout << "overlapp detected !" << endl;
            }
            grid[i] = test_value_id;
        }

        ++test_value_id;
    });
}

void reset_common()
{
    grid.fill(0);
    test_values.clear();
}

int main()
{
    const float scale = ((float)grid_length / (float)original_length);
    cout << "scale: " << scale << " length per pixel: " << ((float)original_length / (float)grid_length) << endl;

    // Example data 1
/*    cout << "Example data 1" << endl;

    test_values.push_back(make_pair(2100, 2800));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(2800, 3600));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(3600, 4500));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(4500, 5500));

    scale_and_add(scale);
    show_grid();

    reset_common();

    // Example data 2
    cout << "Example data 2" << endl;

    test_values.push_back(make_pair(960, 1440));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(1440, 1920));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(1920, 2400));

    scale_and_add(scale);
    show_grid();

    reset_common();

    // Example data 3
    cout << endl << "Example data 3" << endl;

    test_values.push_back(make_pair(896, 1344));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(1344, 1792));
    test_values.push_back(make_pair(1792, 2240));

    scale_and_add(scale);
    show_grid();

    reset_common();*/

    // Generated data - to quickly find the problem
    cout << "Generated data" << endl;

    auto to_op = [&](const size_t v) {
        return v * (original_length / grid_length) * 1.3; // 1.4 and 1.5 are also good values to show the problem
    };
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t psize = 1; // Note this value (length) and check it with the displayed one, you'll be surprised !
    for (size_t g = 0; g < 10; ++g) {
        test_values.push_back(make_pair(to_op(pos), to_op(pos + psize)));
        pos += psize;
    }

    scale_and_add(scale);
    show_grid();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
scale: 0.003125 length per pixel: 320
    Generated data
1:
 0 => 416 length: 416
 0 (0) => 1 (1.3) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
2:
 416 => 832 length: 416
 1 (1.3) => 3 (2.6) length: 2 (1.3) (scaled)
3:
 832 => 1248 length: 416
 3 (2.6) => 4 (3.9) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
4:
 1248 => 1664 length: 416
 4 (3.9) => 5 (5.2) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
5:
 1664 => 2080 length: 416
 5 (5.2) => 7 (6.5) length: 2 (1.3) (scaled)
6:
 2080 => 2496 length: 416
 7 (6.5) => 8 (7.8) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
7:
 2496 => 2912 length: 416
 8 (7.8) => 9 (9.1) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
8:
 2912 => 3328 length: 416
 9 (9.1) => 10 (10.4) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
9:
 3328 => 3744 length: 416
 10 (10.4) => 12 (11.7) length: 2 (1.3) (scaled)
10:
 3744 => 4160 length: 416
 12 (11.7) => 13 (13) length: 1 (1.3) (scaled)
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

This code example demonstrates my problem more clearly.

Interesting fact: mingw-g++, which i used to write this example, shows slightly different values. I usually use visual studio 2010 but couldn't this time because I'm not at home.

Comment: Pictures would probably help to understand the problem here.

Comment: I don't have a picture demonstrating this issue.
The "Displayed grid" is direct copy and pasted output of the console program i used to find this problem. But i can show you an image of what it _closely_ will look like with graphics:
[link](http://i55.tinypic.com/s4cj9s.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah +1 to get you back up, the question is OK.
I don't know why people thing it is so fun to downvote without even leaving a comment.

Well, to the question :-)

Usually when drawing you have this overlapping issues and in 3D computer graphics with scanline renderers (DirectX & OpenGL for ex) they usually Skip exactly one pixel (say all on the right and down side).
Maybe this can help you out.

It is possible too that when the division is perfect, you don't have the artefacts so you must maybe deal with that (ie. if the value is a 'perfect integer', for example 185.000000 then don't remove the last pixel).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting the problem statement but I will take a stab at it. You have ranges of information that you are displaying contigously a range is usually [a,b). Everything is fine when a and b directly represent the pixels that you are trying to draw, but you are having problems when you want to scale the whole thing.

Not dealing with multiple rows of pixels, if you have two ranges R1=[a,b) and R2=[b,c) unscaled you just draw from a to b-1 and from b to c-1 and your ranges are drawn so what is the problem in the scaled case drawing from (int)(a*scale) to ((int)(b*scale)-1) and then from (int)(b*scale) to ((int)(c*scale)-1), you can use any float to int conversion, rounding, floor or ceiling and you should be ok.

The next problem area would be if your scale ranges amount to less than 1 pixel, in this case you might need to detect if the size of the scaled range is 0 and carry a correction factor (in pixels) that is added at the end of the calculation.

Pseudocode

```
DrawRanges(List<Range> ranges, float scale)
  int carry = 0;
  foreach(Range range in ranges)
  {
      int newStart = ceiling(range.start*scale);
      int newEnd = ceiling(range.end*scale)-1;

      if (newStart <= newEnd)
      {
        newEnd = newStart;
        ++carry;
      }
      DrawRange(newStart+carry,newEnd+carry);
  }
```

This will eventually fail if you have more Ranges than blocks in your scaled down grid, you would have to figure out how to drop ranges completely. In draw rang you map your index to an actual block coordinate.

Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: Please see the newly added code example, i apologize, i should have added a code example to begin with.

Comment: What I can see in your code is that you are scaling the start, end and the block length separately, you should definitely only scale only two of these three values and have the third follow, this way the set will be consistent, so either scale start, end and calculate length from that or scale start and length and calculate end from that. Scaling all three will get you in trouble with rounding especially using round(). Is this homework btw ?

Comment: The length is there as a debug value. If you look closely i'm just printing the length. Homework, i wish, then i could just ask a teacher about this. This is just another fun pet project.

Comment: Since you asked if this was homework. Are you saying the solution is easy and i'm just not seeing it ?

Comment: No, this kind of problem sounds like a homework problem. You are looking at a discretization problem, the extra samples are not really claryfing. At the last one it looks like, all the ranges are contigoud isn't that what you expect ? I don't know what you are expecting, everytime you round you are introducing an error, eventually you might have to correct for that error